# How to delete the contents of an entire column from an external database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I read data from an external database and I want to delete the contents of an entire column from it.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have to post your database class and what have you tried till now ?

Comment: Do you want to delete the contents of the column, or the column?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on the Sqlite database then add this in your Database Class File.

From: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html:

(11) How do I add or delete columns from an existing table in SQLite.

SQLite has limited ALTER TABLE support that you can use to add a column to the end of a table or to change the name of a table. If you want to make more complex changes in the structure of a table, you will have to recreate the table. You can save existing data to a temporary table, drop the old table, create the new table, then copy the data back in from the temporary table.

For example, suppose you have a table named "t1" with columns names "a", "b", and "c" and that you want to delete column "c" from this table. The following steps illustrate how this could be done:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(a,b);
INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT a,b FROM t1;
DROP TABLE t1;
CREATE TABLE t1(a,b);
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT a,b FROM t1_backup;
DROP TABLE t1_backup;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `UPDATE` the column value with its default value (i.e. `''` for a text column, `0` for an integer, `NULL` for a nullable, ...), specifying no condition (no `WHERE` clause).
This will replace ALL the values on that column with a default value.